# How to trigger click on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to automatically "click" an item when the page loads.

I've tried using

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click');
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work? However, when I enter `$("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click');` into Firebug's console and run the script, it works.

Can the trigger event be used on load?

Comment: It should work, unless the element is added later.  Can you post a demo?  (Try http://jsbin.com)

Comment: Can you post the scenario where you want to do this? Sounds like obtrusive javascript

Comment: Where is your `click` handler added?

Comment: http://dev.gentlecode.net/blossomsoft/portfolio-single.html

It uses a jQuery Galleria plugin (http://devkick.com/lab/galleria/) to create a gallery from an unordered list of images. I'm trying to fire off the big image on page load instead of having to click on the thumb.

Comment: And here is my scripts file: http://dev.gentlecode.net/blossomsoft/js/scripts.js

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The click handler that you are trying to trigger is most likely also attached via `$(document).ready()`. What is probably happening is that you are triggering the event before the handler is attached. The solution is to use `setTimeout`:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click');
    },10);
});
```

A delay of 10ms will cause the function to run immediately after all the `$(document).ready()` handlers have been called.

OR you check if the element is ready:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
  $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").ready(function() {
    $(this).click();
  });    
});
```

Comment: Nice. It's odd that it's running in order and still misses the declaration by a hair. This solved it for me.

Comment: Your answer helped me in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215964/why-window-load-isnt-working-when-the-request-comes-from-outside-the-page-but/

Very much appreciated.

Comment: Appreciated first of all. But why the second solution (check if the element is ready) is not working. Can you explain a little bit more? Thank you :]

Answer (score 8):

```
$(function(){

    $(selector).click();

});
```

Comment: API reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click. 
Note that `$(callback)` is equivalent to `$("document").ready(callback);`

Comment: Same effect - works in Firebug, but when entered to my scripts file, it doesn't. Firebug doesn't give any errors as well. Does it matter there are other scripts in the file in $(function() { .. }); as well?

Answer (score 6):

```
$("document").ready({
    $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").click(function(){alert('i work click triggered'});
}); 

$("document").ready(function() { 
    $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click'); 
});
```

just make sure the click handler is added prior to the trigger event in the call stack sequence.

```
  $("document").ready(function() { 
        $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").trigger('click'); 
    }); 

   $("document").ready({
        $("ul.galleria li:first-child img").click(function(){alert('i fail click triggered'});
    });
```

Comment: Yours is the most appropriate answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$("your id here").trigger("click");
});
```