# How to trigger Click as a page loads using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have seen a ton of posts about this, but none worked as I was trying to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#link_to_content').tigger('click');
});
```

Once the page is loaded I want to trigger the click. I know its weird to open a link once a page loads but in this case it makes sense.

I am using jquery 1.7

Comment: Is it a typo in the post, or your code? `tigger` should be `trigger`.  Unless you want a tiger bouncing up and down on your page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger click on page load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load)

Answer (score 3):

should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#link_to_content').trigger('click');
});
```

working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zpnQv/

EDIT:

if you want to follow the link you could do something like:

```
HTML:
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com/" id="link_to_content">Click Me</a>


JS:
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#link_to_content").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        alert("going to " + href);
        window.location = href;
    });
    $('#link_to_content').trigger('click');
});
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/omudih/1/

Comment: Clicks aren't actually followed to their href when using jQuery, likely a security concern.  This demo only works in theory by doing the alert in the click handler.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [won't click on links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694803/597122).  My own interpretation is that this is a bit of a security risk, which is more or less what the linked answer boils down to.

However, as the linked answer states, you can simply select the Javascript `HtmlDOMElement` and `.click()` it.

In other words: `$('#link_to_content')[0].click();`

Answer (score 0):

The click handler that you are trying to trigger is most likely also attached via $(document).ready(). What is probably happening is that you are triggering the event before the handler is attached. The solution is to use setTimeout:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#link_to_content").trigger('click');
},10);
});
```

A delay of 10ms will cause the function to run immediately after all the $(document).ready() handlers have been called.

OR

use trigger in call back function of .load();

you can also use .on() instead of trigger()

```
$('div_to_load').load("#link_to_content",function(){
$("#link_to_content").trigger('click');
});
```

.on() example

```
$('div_to_click').on("click",".title",function(){
alert('sdfdsf');
});
```