# Run a click event when page is load using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already search this functionality to this url : [How to trigger click on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load) but it's not working in my site.

Well, I have a page where a popup box appear when I click on a "project" link. here is the code :

```
$(".project").click(function() {
    $("#first, #second, .allContactsContent").slideUp("slow", function() {
    $("#third").slideDown("slow");  
    $("#contacts, #showSearchResult, #all_projects").hide();            
    });
});
```

I want to load this "project" click event when page is load, how can I do this ? What I am trying now is following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".project").trigger('click');
    alert(1);
},10);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(document)` without the `"`s?

Comment: Thank you @JakubMichálek

Comment: @creativeartbd sorry bit late .. Good catch JakubMichálek

Answer (score 0):

here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/dcy5ey9f/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="project"> </div>
```

Comment: please add the description , instead of posting link to fiddle.

Comment: @Runner  i wanted to make it runnable one, and the fiddle is working fine. Just want to present a runnable solution. Thanks for your input and time

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a trigger a "click" event when nobody has clicked on anything. The event handler code should be refactored so a click event is not required:

```
function showAndHideStuff() {
    $("#first, #second, .allContactsContent").slideUp("slow", function() {
        $("#third").slideDown("slow");  
        $("#contacts, #showSearchResult, #all_projects").hide();            
    });
}
```

Then pass the function in as a `ready` event handler, as well as using that function as the `click` handler:

```
$(document)
    .ready(showAndHideStuff)
    .ready(function() {
        $(".project").click(showAndHideStuff);
    });
```