# Auto Click link when page load with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I try to create a javascript to click on the link(id="bigPicLink") once the page load but it not working. New in javascript here. Please help. Thank you.

```
<?php

// display modal
if (isset($_GET[id]) && $_GET[id] != "" ) {

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM tattoo WHERE `productno` = '$_GET[id]'");
    $tattoo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);?>

    <a href="#" id="bigPicLink" title="title" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bigPic" data-title="<?php echo $tattoo['title'];?>" data-id="<?php echo $tattoo['productno'];?>" data-price="<?php echo $tattoo['price'];?>" data-picturebig="../mainpic/<?php echo $tattoo['picture'];?>">adasdsada</a>

    <?php
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bigPicLink').click();
        document.getElementById('bigPicLink').click();
        });
        </script>";

} ?>
```

Comment: I think you are creating a recursive dependency, you only need a line with `$('#bigPicLink').trigger('click')` inside of the `$(document).ready`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load

Answer (score 0):

Translate for @mitogh answer :)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#bigPicLink').trigger('click')
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe when you was calling `$('#bigPicLink').click()` it wasn't create in DOM, so DOM cannot know `#bigPicLink` is what?

You can try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#bigPicLink').click();
}, 1000);
```

});

or needn't `$(document).ready` just only `setTimeuut`

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#bigPicLink').click();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Quick note. `.trigger("click")` is faster because it will call one less function.

Comment: but maybe not sure `#bigPicLink` was create in DOM