# Auto click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want using greasmonkey auto click a button after page load.
this button has this properties:

```
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
```

This code works but when page is reloaded it does not work.

This button has This properties first time page is loaded:

```
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
```

And then second time page is reloaded has This properties:

```
<button style="outline: 1px solid blue;" id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
```

Comment: Put an alert in your function and see is it really clicked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger click on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load)

Comment: Why would you want event to call event to call function not to just call StartVisit(1) on DOM ready?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 there might be other event listeners attached

Comment: @AyushGupta StartVisit(1) can call other functions - button clicking script just doesn't seem like the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do through `$(window).load(function(){..});`

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");
});
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");
});

function StartVisit(id){
 alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
```

***Note:-***

You can use `$(document).ready(function(){$("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");});` too

You can use `<body onload ="StartVisit(1)">` too

Comment: @AyushGupta  OP says:- `auto click a button after page load.`

Comment: @dheerajKumar  glad to help you :):). Btw you can try other otipns as i suggested to check that they worked or not. Will help you in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");
});
```

It will trigger the click event of button on page load.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. you can use [`onload()`](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event as this

```js
function StartVisit(x){
 console.log("click " +x);
}
```

```html
<body onload="StartVisit(0)">
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
</body>
```

or using jQuery event

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");
});

function StartVisit(x){
    console.log("click " +x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit
    <i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You js function must execute when the DOM is fully loaded. [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnStartVisit").trigger("click");
});

function StartVisit(id){
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnStartVisit" onclick="StartVisit(1)" class="btn waves-effect waves-light green">start visit<i class="material-icons dp48 left">flash_on</i></button>
```