# jQuery on load detect which radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Working example: https://codepen.io/stevland/pen/arOEEQ.

I am using jQuery to change the opacity of a corresponding table based on which radio button is toggled on/off.

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {
    $("input:radio").each(function() {
        $(this).closest("table").toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

It works well except for one caveat: when visiting the page one has to click a radio button to initiate the function.

I'd like to expand the code to work as soon as the page is loaded, based on which radio button is already checked:

```
<input type="radio" checked />
```

Comment: `$('input:radio:checked').trigger('click')` after your existing code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger click on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2060136/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey That worked! Thank you.