# TableSorter doesn't get styled until a column is clicked

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

I am using the [TableSorter jquery plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/tablesorter/). Functionally it works fine. I don't load my `tablesorter` table statically when the page loads, but rather in an ajax call, as soon as the static page load finishes. The reason I do this is because users can make changes that affect the data in this table, so sometimes I need the js in the page to re-pull and reload it via ajax from the server.

Here is the problem: After the `tablesorter` table is built, the styles aren't applied. It's as though no styles exist on it. However, as soon as I click any of the columns to sort, suddenly all the styles get applied and appear as expected.

You can see this behavior in action by [clicking here](https://www.rightnowdone.com/_badstyles.html). Click the **Dependencies** tab to see my table. At least in Chrome, you should see no styles. Then click any column header and watch the styles be applied.

*Before styles are applied:*
[image]

*After clicking a column header, and styles suddenly get applied:*
[image]

Question: How can I force the styles to apply when initially loaded, without having to wait for a column header to be clicked?

Comment: Code would be pretty handy to solve this. But you could 'simulate' a click to sort one of the columns on page load I guess if you're being hacky and/or using a 3rd party plugin to sort.

Comment: How to trigger a click on load with JQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load

Comment: EGC, click on load -- great tip. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into your html code, When user clicks on the "Dependencies tab" run the following line, then you can see the styles being applied. I verified on chrome "console".

$('table').trigger('sortReset');

OR add the below piece of code on pageload, it triggers sortReset when the dependenices tab is clicked, Just once, then the handler is removed.

```
$("#tabDependencies").parent().click(function() {  
  $('table').trigger('sortReset');
  $(this).off("click");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Murali, it works! Your 2nd example works, but I couldn't get your 1st example to work.